# Android app crashes on phone.

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've tried to develop my own app but now that i wanna see how it looks on my phone it says "Appname has stopped". Im installing the app via dropbox.

Here's a copy of the MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.aikk;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button mBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.northpowerramsor);
    mBtn1.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void onClick(View view) {
    Log.i("clicks","You Clicked B1");
    Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, Ramsor.class);
    startActivity(i);
    // Do something in response to button
}

    }
```

And here's a copy of Ramsor.java

```
    public class Ramsor extends Activity {

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_Ramsor);
            //Vettefan var det här är till med när jag skulle göra quick fix på       den kom jag till nån knas layout sida

    // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

And the Android.Manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.aikk"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
  <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="1"
       android:targetSdkVersion="19"
       android:maxSdkVersion="19" />
  <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
     <activity
        android:name="com.example.aikk.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.aikk.Ramsor"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ramsor"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.AIKK.MainActivity" >
    <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.AIKK.MainActivity" /> >
    </activity>

    </application>
  </manifest>
```

Any thoughts would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: `Crash => Stacktrace`. Show us it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here , you are trying to cast the activity(this) to OnClickListener

```
mBtn1.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
```

The solution is to make your activity implements OnClickListener and create the unimplemented method

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

should be

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
```

There can be other reasons for the crash as well in which case  it is better you post the stacktrace.

You can do as below using annonymous inner class

```
mBtn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
         public void onClick(View v)
         {
           // do something
         }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your class definition to implement OnClickListener:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
```

...and set the click listener on mBtn1 as follows:

```
mBtn1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

try below this instead of `mBtn1.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);`

```
mBtn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

       // Activity to do onclick .

    }
});
return true;
```